# Count function not working in PHP to find size of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$datas = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($firstQueryResult)) {
    $phones["Id"] = $row['person_id'];
    $phones["Latitude"] = $row['lat'];
    $phones["Longitude"] = $row['lng'];
    $phones["Distance"] = $row['distance'];
    $phones["DateTime"] = $row['location_datetime'];
    $datas["mydata"][] = $phones;
}

echo "Count = ".count($datas); // always returning 1 while i have more than 1 recor
echo "Count = ".sizeof($datas); // always returning 1 while i have more than 1 record
```

Anyone can please help me.

Comment: What about `echo "Count = ".count($datas['mydata']);`

Comment: If the parameter is not an array or not an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
echo "Count = ".count($datas['mydata']);
echo "Count = ".sizeof($datas['mydata']);
```

Answer (score 0):

$datas has only 1 element -> "mydata".

You want to count the number of entries in mydata, so :

```
count($datas["mydata"]);
```